# GWT: Setting the FontSize in a DataGrid Cell

Tags: css, gwt, datagrid

I am trying to modify the Textsize in a DataGrid.

I am able to set the Color and the FontWeigt, but not the Size.
Why not? Why am I not able to override the Size?

Code:

```
        measResultTable.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<MeasResultOverviewEntry>()
        {
            @Override
            public String getStyleNames(MeasResultOverviewEntry entry, int rowIndex)
            {
                return "measResultRow";
            }
        });
```

CSS:

```
.measResultRow 
{   
        font-size: 2em; !important;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold; !important;
}
```

Any ideas why color and font-weight are applied but font-size isn't?

Regards,
VanDahlen

Answer (score 0):

```
.meaResultRow{   
   font-size: 2em !important;
   color: red;
   font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

you may write `important` in the wrong place, if still not right, you can try wrting `px` defining the font and check if it works.

Comment: Solution: One needs to set the Style in the Columns: TextColumn.setCellStyleNames()